# Find Google API scopes again

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I started messing with Google API's today for the first time. I now can't remember which exact scopes I picked when making the API and I can't find it anywhere in the developer dashboard. Where can I see the scopes I have requested?

Comment: you request scopes in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you dont really pick scopes in google cloud console you enable your application to use scopes.  Or you define which apis your application is intending to use and which scopes.

Under library on the left you can define which API your application will be using

[image]

Under Oauth consent screen.

[image]

Click edit app then go to the second page here you can define which scopes your app will be using this is used during the verification process

[image]

To be clear this just tells Google these are the scopes you intend to use.  You will still have to add them in your code and there is nothing stopping  you from adding other ones or not using some.   This is just for verification.

Comment: Great answer. I was including scopes not enabled and then was throwing errors when refreshing.